# Vetores - Separar negativos e positivos

Tags: c++, vector

tenho que fazer um programa que receba um vetor de 8 números e retorne 2 vetores, o primeiro com os números positivos do vetor de 8 posições, e o segundo com os números negativos.

O PROBLEMA É QUE EU NÃO SEI COMO UTILIZAR VECTOR, já que os dois últimos vetores não devem possuim capacidade definida..

Isso está fazendo com que meu segundo vetor "perca" de alguma maneira as posições dos números positivos que são digitados primeiro. Não sei se ficou claro.

Se puderem ajudar, ficaria grato.

MEU CÓDIGO:

using namespace std;
int main(){

```
vector<int> vet(8);

for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    cin>>vet.at(i);
}

vector<int> vet1(8);
vector<int> vet2(8);

int cont1=0,cont2=0;

for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    if(vet.at(i)>=0){
        vet1.at(i)=vet.at(i);
        cont1++;
    }else{
        vet2.at(i)=vet.at(i);
        cont2++;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<cont1;i++){
    cout<<vet1.at(i)<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<cont2;i++){
    cout<<vet2.at(i)<<" ";
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Thiago! Por favor [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/213206/edit) sua pergunta, e explique melhor o problema que você está tendo (qual é o resultado esperado? qual o resultado atual?) - normalmente perguntas com enunciado de problema não são muito bem vistas, pois a comunidade termina achando que você quer que ela faça o trabalho por você - sugiro que você remova esse trecho e escreva detalhadamente apenas o problema que você quer resolver.

Comment: Não vejo problema no enunciado, ele ajuda entender o que está fazendo, tem um código que tentou, mas falta dizer qual é o problema, qual a dúvida.

Comment: O problema é que minha resolução está errada. O vetor de números positivos que está sendo impresso na tela tem sucesso, porém o segundo está com problemas. Além disso, eu não poderia declarar o tamanho do "vet1" e "vet2", já que não sei a quantidade de números positivos e negativos.

Comment: Faz bem em fazer os vetores com o mesmo tamanho que o de entrada. Olhe a resposta que dei a baixo, espero ter ajudado, qualquer duvide me comunique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que esta fazendo a inserção nos vetores de forma errônea, pois esta utilizando o mesmo `int` para iterar o `loop` e para adicionar em cada vetor.

Por exemplo se vem o vetor 1,-1,67,...

o vetor vet1 vai ficar 1,"lixo",67,...
e o vetor vet2 vai ficar "lixo",-1,"lixo"

você deve utilizar os contadores como índices do vetores de armazenamento como segue o código:

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    if(vet.at(i)>=0){
        vet1.at(cont1)=vet.at(i);
        cont1++;
    }else{
        vet2.at(cont2)=vet.at(i);
        cont2++;
    }
}
```

me diz depois se funcionou. =D

Comment: Mateus, muito obrigado pela resposta!!! Deu certo. Estou com mais uma dúvida sobre a declaração do tamanho do "vet1" e "vet2", pois eu não sei a quantidade de números positivos e negativos que o usuário irá digitar, sendo assim, eu não deveria então criar um vetor sem antes declarar seu tamanho inicial? **EDIT** Digo isso porque meu professor fala muito em não desperdiçar memória atoa, fazendo com que o programa fique o mais leve possível.

Comment: Bom é sempre bom poupar memória, deixar o programa mais leve, seu professor está certo. Você pode ver mais sobre isso se pesquisar sobre alocação dinâmica de vetores. Voce pode fazer de diversas maneiras. Acho que o que seu professor está querendo que faça é um vetor de ponteiros . Pode aprender um pouco mais aqui:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: Obrigado novamente!!